# View Completed Elasticsearch Tasks

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run daily tasks using Elasticsearch's update by query API. I can find currently running tasks but need a way to view all tasks, including completed.

I've reviewed the ES docs for the Update By Query API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query

And the Task API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#tasks

Task API shows how to get the status of a currently running task with `GET _tasks/[taskId]`, or all running tasks - `GET _tasks`. But I need to see a history of all tasks ran.

How do I see a list of all completed tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation,

> The Task Management API is new and should still be considered a beta
>   feature.It allows to retrieve information about the tasks **currently executing** on one or more nodes in the cluster.

It still in beta version, so using this currently you'll only able to do these-

1. Possible to retrieve information for a particular task using `GET /_tasks/<task_id>`, where you can also use the **detailed** request parameter to get more information about the running tasks(also you can use other params as per the support)
2. Tasks can be also **listed** using `GET _cat/tasks` version of the list tasks command, which accepts the same arguments as the standard list tasks command.
3. If a long-running task supports **cancellation**, it can be cancelled with the cancel tasks API, with `POST _tasks/oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:12345/_cancel`
4. Task can be **grouped** with `GET _tasks?group_by=parents`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. I really wish there were a way to see even a history of all completed tasks. Maybe in future versions. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Correct answer is as given below by @tpopov

Answer (score 9):

A bit late to the party, but you can check the tasks in the `.tasks` system index.

You can query this index, as any other regular index.
For the updateByQuery task you can do:

```
curl -XPOST -sS "elastic:9200/.tasks/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "completed": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "task.action": "indices:data/write/update/byquery"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: I got index_not_found_exception...{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [.tasks]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":".tasks","index_uuid":"_na_","index":".tasks"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [.tasks]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":".tasks","index_uuid":"_na_","index":".tasks"},"status":404}

Comment: same thing here, tried with _tasks as well, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Works for me. I'm using 6.8. I suspect the tasks index doesn't exist unless you've run a task. 
You can use `GET /_cat/indices` to see if ".tasks" exists.