# How to get results of completed ElasticSearch task?

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

The Task Management Api: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html

returns data about currently running task.

What is the way to get results of the task that has been completed?

I tried the solution from here: [View Completed Elasticsearch Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125914/view-completed-elasticsearch-tasks)

but it does not work. Returns the same error as the other guys mentioned:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [.tasks]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":".tasks","index_uuid":"na","index":".tasks"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [.tasks]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":".tasks","index_uuid":"na","index":".tasks"},"status":404}
```

Can anyone suggest?

UPDATE. This is what I get when running: `GET _cat/indices/.*?v`

I replaced some of the sensitive data with `XXXX`

```
health status index                           uuid   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .kibana_account_name            XXXX   1   1          2            0     23.1kb         11.5kb
green  open   .kibana_XXXX                    XXXX   1   1          1            0     10.2kb          5.1kb
green  open   .opensearch-notebooks           XXXX   1   1          0            0       416b           208b
green  open   .kibana_1                       XXXX   1   1         14            1       75kb         37.5kb
green  open   .opendistro_security            XXXX   1   2          9            3    171.9kb         57.3kb
```

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/indices/.*?v`?

Comment: @Val thanks for the response. I updated the initial post as comments section did not allow to enter all that info

Comment: Weird that there is no `.tasks` index... Where are you hosted? AWS?

Comment: @Val, yes, AWS. I'm using OpenSearch DashBoards if that is important